# Webpack-reactjs proxy requests to avoid CORS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My **React App** is hosted on my localhost and assigned a domain on /etc/hosts: **[www.domain.test:8080](http://www.domain.test:8080)**
My **API** is hosted within my Vagrant box and assigned a domain on /etc/hosts: **api.domain.test**

What I want is to make requests to **https://www.domain.test/api/*** and webpack to reverse them under the hood to https://api.domain.test/* to avoid getting the CORS.

I've tried the code block below to reverse my requests through webpack:

```
proxy: { 
      "/api": { 
        target: 'https://api.domain.test', 
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
        secure: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {
          Connection: 'keep-alive'
        }
      }  
    }
```

But I get **[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request**

Is this an obvious fix or another way to achieve it?

**Update:** Serving the React app thourgh HTTP (instead of HTTPS) and the API through HTTP as well, it works as expected.

Comment: which http proxy version you are using ?

Comment: @ZiaurRehman this directive is inside the devServer block in my webpack.js file. I haven't installed any module, if that is what you are asking for. ("webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3")

Comment: which library handle your above code?

Comment: @ZiaurRehman webpack version 5.27.1 . At this point I should mention that using http instead of https, proxy works as expected.

Comment: in that case you have to use proxy pass on server side, all https request send to http

Comment: @ZiaurRehman yes that is exactly what I did. For development purposes, it's fine.